# Designing simple database relation (school)

Tags: sql, database, database-design

I'm new to designing database relations. Could someone have a look at my relations and see if it makes sense? This is what I've done,

## Relations

Membership [**one to many**] Club
Membership [**one to many**] Student
Membership [**one to many**] Positions
Category [**one to many**] Club
Category [**one to many**] Position

**Description**
1) Every student may be in multiple clubs.
2) They hold a position in each of these clubs (e.g. President, Chairman).
3) The positions belong to a particular category (e.g. Sports, Clubs, Student Council).
4) The clubs belong to a particular category as well (e.g. Sports, Clubs, Student Council).

## Models

**Membership**

- clubID
- studentID
- positionID

**Club**

- id
- name
- categoryID

**Student**

- id
- name
- class

**Position**

- id
- name
- description
- points
- categoryID

**Category**

- id
- name

Comment: The one problem I see here is that there is no way to enforce the rule that the position and club should both belong to the same category (which isn't specified in the description but does make sense). In fact, I would argue that "*3) The positions belong to a particular category*" is redundant - the club already belongs to a category, and a position without a club doesn't make sense.

Comment: I would drop the link between positions and categories. Makes little sense. If there is nothing more than the name in the Category table, and if your data volume is low (<10.000 recs) I would probably even drop the Category table (even if *academically*, it's the right thing.

Comment: @ZoharPeled Thanks for replying. The reason why "_position belongs to a particular category_" is because upon new creation of club, the form can dynamically populate positions belonging to a particular category. Does that make sense?

Comment: @PatrickHonorez Thanks for replying. What do you think of the above comment I made?

Comment: The design of your tables should be done to properly represent the reality you deal with, according to Relational Database normalisation rules. Your forms come later in the process and should definitely have no impact on your data structure  !! And by the way you can have the source of a combo linked to itself...

Comment: Have a look at the chapter "Modeling of different link types" in [the book](https://www.amazon.com/dp/2956300806)