# A simple question about which table should have the foreign key of the other table in on-many relationship

Tags: database, database-design

Just an example, say a `customer` could have multiple `orders`. That's One-Many relationship.

When I design database tables like this example, I always end up with thinking whether I should have `customers` table having a `order_id` *foreign key* column or should I have the `orders` table having a `customer_id`  *foreign key*. Which way to go?

Is there a rule or convention in DB design that which way is better to decide which table should contain a foreign key of the other table?  (I hope I expressed my question clearly with that example.)

**To clarify:** I know I should declare `customer_id` in `orders` table in my example, but I am seeking for a rule/convention (if there is) to help me in future to easily decide which table should declare foreign key column in general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a One-to-many relationship, the foreign key (FK) is always in the 'many' table, pointing to the primary key (PK) of the 'one' table.
If you happen to have a Many-to-many relationship, then you have to create a *relationship table* containing both PKs. E.g: One *Student* can choose many *Courses*, one *Course* has many *Students*. The relationship table could be called 'Enrollments' and will contain both PKs.

Have a look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53426910/78522), or search for 'relational database normalisation'.

Answer (score 0):

You should have the orders table having a Customer_id.

The reason why? You want to add orders to the orders table without having to update the customer table. Also you don't want to keep a list of orders on the customer.

One customer can have multiple orders, the foreign key is designed to allow multiple instances of the same value. Hope this is the answer you needed

Comment: Yes, I understand that. But that is just my example, I am actually more interested in an answer that could tell "how to decide" in general which table should declare foreign key.  Is there a rule or convention? Something like (my assuption) "always declare foreign key in the table of the X side of one-many relationship" .

Comment: Well in general, in the case of a one-many relation ship, the many should always have the foreign key declared. The one is a unique record which can be used multiple times by the many relation. Therefor the many has always got to have a foreign key.

Answer (score 0):

I think the key verb for deciding what goes where is *has* (In case of One-to-many relationship). If entity **A** *has* some entities **B**, then the foreign key should be declared on the right side of the relationship **A** *has* **B**, i.e. in **B**.